# Getting access to Mesibo video and audio stream from outside a browser (i.e on a server)

Tags: node.js, webrtc, mesibo

I would like to process audio and video from a [Mesibo](https://mesibo.com/) conference on the server side and then, if possible, feed the processed stream back in as a new publisher (participant) in a different group (conference).

By current best guess would be something like this...

1. Run the Mesibo Javascript API in a virtual browser using node [browser-run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-run) and Xvfb
2. Connect to the conference in the browser and somehow extract the necessary WebRTC connection details and feed this back to the node process controlling the virtual browser
3. Connect to the conference using node [webrtc-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-client)

Having to run a virtual browser every time seems like overkill. Also I have no idea where I would get the webrtc connection details (step 2) from in the virtual browser. Does the Mesibo Javascript API expose these anywhere?

Assumedly if I could get the above working then I could use the same webrtc-client instance to feed the process back into the conference, but if I wanted to feed it into a different conference then I'd have to create another virtual browser.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

mesibo on-premise conference server exposes RTP API, possibly that should help. However, the on-premise conference server will be available publicly in Feb'21 so you will have to wait.

How would you expect step 2? are you looking to access the underlying peerconnection?